# XSLT sort Arabic letters

Tags: xslt

I have XML like:

```
<Answers>
  <QuestionAnswer Id="1" Answer="أقل من 16 عام"/>
  <QuestionAnswer Id="2" Answer="17 – 24 عامً"/>
  <QuestionAnswer Id="3" Answer="25- 34 عامً"/>
  <QuestionAnswer Id="4" Answer="35-  44 عامً"/>
  <QuestionAnswer Id="5" Answer="أكثر من 45 عامً"/>
</Answers>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//QuestionAnswer">
  <xsl:variable name="AnswerId" select="@Id"/>
  <xsl:variable name="AnswerText" select="@Answer"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',$AnswerId, ' &quot;', $AnswerText, '&quot;')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

and return should be the order from XML, but is in an odd order because of Arabic characters.

How can I fix this?

```
1 "أقل من 16 عام" 
2 "17 – 24 عامً" 
3 "25- 34 عامً" 
4 "35-  44 عامً" 
5 "أكثر من 45 عامً"
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you printing the result of your transformation on a terminal? If so, try redirecting the output to a file, and look at that file with a decent text editor. You might find that the problem is only a display problem.

Comment: it is silly but i have a problem with desplaying data corectly with arabic letters

Comment: result printed to file shouls be :

Comment: 1" "أقل من 16 عام"2 "17 – 24 عامً" .................... but is ....... 1 "أقل من 16 عام" 2 "17 – 24 عامً" 3 "25- 34 عامً" 4 "35- 44 عامً" 5 "أكثر من 45 عامً maybe reading from right to left is problem

Comment: Why do you expect the second answer to be first?

Comment: @karolio007 You need to view the result in an application that supports RTL text writing direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort on the value of @Answer then you should be able to use

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//QuestionAnswer">
  <xsl:sort select="@Answer" lang="ar"/>
```

You can further qualify the language code, e.g. `lang="ar-EG"` gives sorting according to the rules for Arabic as used in Egypt. I don't know anything about Arabic so I don't know if this is necessary.

Of course, it might be that your XSLT processor does not support all possible language codes.

Comment: The question is very unclear, but I think the OP wants to sort the entries by the numerical values contained within the answers, and to sort the numerical values within a single answer, too.

Comment: Thank You Michael, I tried this solution but it is not working

Comment: It is not sorting values by numbers. Strange also is position() function result. It returns Answer text value not a real position only in 'arabic situation'.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the RTL unicode to your sentence:

```
<xsl:variable name="rightToLeftUnicode" select="'&#x200E;'"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',$AnswerId, ' &quot;', $AnswerText, '&quot;', $rightToLeftUnicode)" />
```